# Going through two CSV file looking for a value in between a range python

Tags: python, csv

the following code stops at the first row of the data1 file.

Instead, it should go throught all the values of the 2nd colomn of data1 and look if the value is in the range of colomn 1 and 2 of each row of data 2

```
with open('data1.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader1 = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
    with open('data2.csv', 'r') as d:
        reader2 = csv.reader(d, delimiter=';')
        for row in reader1:
            for line in reader2:
                if (row[0] == line[1]) and (line[2] <= row[1] <= line[3]):
                    print(line[0] + ' ' + row[1])
```

Comment: `reader1` and `reader2` only go through the file once.  So when you use `reader2` for an inner loop it's only going to work on the first iteration of the outer loop.  After that it's all used up.  But don't fix this by repeatedly recreating `reader2` inside your outer loop.  Instead fix your algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reader1` and `reader2` only go through the file once. So when you read through all of `reader2` to check the first row `reader1` it gets all used up.  When you try to check another row from `reader1`, there are no more rows to read from `reader2`.

A naive fix would be to put `d.seek(0)` before the line `for line in reader2:` which would reset the file pointer back to the beginning of the file.  Don't do this because it is a very slow way to process your files.

A better way would be to store the lines of `reader2` in such a way that you only iterate over lines that are likely to be matches.  Since one of your criteria is `row[0] == line[1]` I have cached the lines in `reader2` by `line[1]`.  (I have kept your convention of naming each row in `reader1` `row` and each row in `reader2` `line`.)

```
from collections import defaultdict
reader2_by_item1 = defaultdict(list)
with open('data1.csv', 'r') as f, open('data2.csv', 'r') as d:
    reader1 = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
    reader2 = csv.reader(d, delimiter=';')
    for line in reader2:
        reader2_by_item1[line[1]].append(line)
    for row in reader1:
        for line in reader2_by_item1[row[0]]: # this tests row[0] == line[1]
            if (line[2] <= row[1] <= line[3]):
                print(line[0] + ' ' + row[1])
```

**Note:**  `line[2] <= row[1] <= line[3]`  This comparison is lexicographical (string comparisions).  If you are trying to compare numerical types you would need to convert them to numeric types.